# Canvas line disappearing

Tags: lazarus

Let's say i draw a green rectangle with TPaintBox on a panel(FillRect method). On this rectangle I make horizontal lines(lineTo method). Then on those lines I put TShape(e.g a square). Now when I change the visibility of the TShape to false part of the line in which there was previously the TShape disappears leaving me with the effect like this:

[image]

How do I do that this part of the line doesn't disappear?

Here's the code + I noticed an odd thing while I was writing this code: if I do not put the showMessage method in the code the line and the tShape will not display. Why is that?

```
var
    Panel1 : TPanel;
    PaintBox1 : TPaintBox;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var t : TShape;

begin

    Panel1 := TPanel.Create(form1);
    Panel1.parent := form1;
    Panel1.Color := clGreen;
    Panel1.Width := 500;
    Panel1.Height := 500;
    Panel1.Top := 0;
    Panel1.Left := 0;

    PaintBox1 := TPaintBox.Create(form1);
    PaintBox1.parent := Panel1;
    PaintBox1.Width := 500;
    PaintBox1.Height := 500;
    PaintBox1.Top := 0;
    PaintBox1.Left := 0;
    //showMessage('eee');
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clWhite;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.line(0,50,PaintBox1.Width,50);

    t := TShape.Create(form1);
    t.parent := Panel1;
    t.Brush.Color := clRed;
    t.Width := 50;
    t.Height := 50;
    t.Top := 25;
    t.Left := 200;
    t.Visible :=false;
end;
```

Comment: You can see the code. We cannot. Instead of describing what you did, please show the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is because you are painting at the wrong point in your program. Painting to a paint box control must happen in the `OnPaint` event handler. The content of a paint box is re-painted on demand. The system does this when it needs to by firing the `OnPaint` event. You need to move the painting code into such an event handler.

If you wish to draw to a persistent canvas then you could consider using a `TImage` instead.